# How to open a virtual File in Android, without saving it to local

Tags: android, file, virtual-file

If there are some files hosted in the server how can we access and view them without saving those Files to storage in Android.

Say suppose there are some .pdf,.png,.doc files in server from my app if user tries to open the file it should open in appropriate app like pdfviewer or Gallery or some app depending on it's mimetype.

Similar to apps like GoogleDrive and OneDrive.